# Batch file - variable won't update when assigned a new value

Tags: batch-file

I have a script that simply pings a box, and if the box replies, it changes a variable called "newstate" to up.  Otherwise it gets set to "down".  For some reason, when I run it on my machine, newstate never gets changed to "up" even though it's online and replies to pings.

I'm probably missing something very small, can you please help?  (I also put in a variable to log status when it changes, but I didn't implement it yet because I can't get the switching to even be recognized).  Ultimate goal is to log when status changes from up to down or vice versa.

**EDIT - Changed %newstate% to !newstate!, still not working.**

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off

title loop test

set system=192.168.0.155
set oldstate=up
set newstate=down

:loop
echo.
echo ...........
echo pre check
echo old state is %oldstate%
echo new state is !newstate!
echo ...........
echo.

:::::: CONNECTIVITY CHECK ::::::
for /f "tokens=5,7" %%a in ('ping -n 1 -4 !system!') do (
if "x%%a"=="xReceived" if "x%%b"=="x1," set newstate=up
)

echo new state is !newstate!

if !newstate! neq up set newstate=down

set log=%time% - %sytem% - !newstate!

if %oldstate% neq !newstate! set oldstate=!newstate!

echo.
echo ...........
echo post check
echo old state is %oldstate%
echo new state is !newstate!
echo ...........
echo.

:::::: DELAY LOOP ::::::
ping -n 10 127.0.0.1 >nul: 2>nul:

goto :loop
endlocal
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well , it worked for me, but since i work with a spanish copy of windows i had to change the `Received` literal and use `recibidos`. Not sure about your local configuration.

It is usual better to check for the presence of the `TTL=` value into the ping response. If it is found, the target is up, else, it is down

```
ping -n 1 192.168.0.155 | find "TTL=" >nul 
if errorlevel 1 (
    set "newstate=down"
) else (
    set "newstate=up"
)
```

So, with a little simplification,

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    title loop test

    set "system=192.168.1.1"
    set "oldState=down"
    set "newState=up"

:loop
    ping -4 -n 1 %system% | find "TTL=" >nul && set "newState=up" || set "newState=down"

    if %newState%==%oldState% (
        echo %time% - %system% still %oldState%
    ) else (
        echo %time% - %system% goes %newState%
        set "oldState=%newState%"
    )
    ping -n 10 127.0.0.1 >nul 2>nul
    goto loop
```

Where the `ping` line should be read as "ping , find ttl= in the output, if found set newState to up, else set newstate to down"

**EDITED** -

This was the usual way of testing for ping response. In IPv4. But when pinging in IPv6, the TTL field is not shown, so we can not check it.

The original reason for testing the `TTL=` in the output of the ping command was the way packet counts and errorlevels are handled. If a packet is lost, errorlevel is set. If no packet lost, no errorlevel. But, pinging a non active machine in the same subnet generates a 'unreachable' response and no packet lost, so, no errorlevel and packet count reflects 0 packet lost. And, ...

Also, almost all the information in the ping output is localized, making it difficult to check the result of the ping command and make it consistent across different OS localizations.

But some things have changed in IPv6 ping. If requested machine is not reachable, packets are lost and errorlevel is set. In same subnet or not.

And, if some packets are lost, but at least one packet is not lost, errorlevel is not set.

So, when working with IPv4, the test for `TTL=` presence in ping outout is a "reliable" way to check the state of the remote machine.

And, when working with IPv6, errorlevel reflects the success of failure of the process.

And, please, note that i'm not a network guru. This is what i have seen when testing. If i'm wrong, please, comment.

Comment: This works perfectly... when I use an IP address.  But if I use my hostname, then it doesn't work.  Any ideas on how to make it work with my hostname instead of IP?

Comment: Is the hostname pingable in cmd (not in script)?

Comment: yup, that's why I was confused why it didn't work with hostname.  I think what I'll do is ping my hostname, parse out the IP address, then use the IP address in the script.

Answer (score 0):

Use !newstate! to get variable value, instead of  %newstate%. This is the way of getting delayed variables values. 
Keep using "setlocal enabledelayedexpansion".

Comment: What did you mean, keep using "setlocal enabledelayexpansion"?  Did I disable it somewhere else?  Can you review the changes I made.  It still isn't working.  Maybe I missed something?

Comment: keep using "setlocal enabledelayexpansion" means you should have this in your script in order to use delayed variables. You did not disabled. Could you please explain what is not working?

Comment: when I use my system name (hostname) it doesn't work (status up/down isn't correct).  But when I enter IP address, it works perfectly.  I'm confused why that happens.

Comment: "IP works and hostname does not work" - indicates there's a problem with DNS functions. You should check in that area. Do all hosts resolve to correct IPs. No conflicts/duplicates etc.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this statement

```
if "x%%a"=="xReceived" if "x%%b"=="x1," set newstate=up
```

which means `if firstcondiion and secondcondition` set ...

So - i'd insert a debug line

```
echo +%%a+%%b+
```

just before this `if` statement, and observe results. The <kbd>+</kbd> is just there as an obvious character to make seeing <kbd>Spaces</kbd> easier.

Remember - `if` is case-sensitive, so if you need case-insensitive, use `if /i`

Also - observe <kbd>Spaces</kbd> as a quoted-string in an `if` incudes any spaces in the match.

There is no point in `delayedexpansion` in this instance, since you are not attempting to read a values that changes within (a parenthesised block of statements). Under these circumstances, `%var%`==`!var!`